# NSTimer how to fix my code

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

How to write code if timer1Elapsed finish to countdown timer then go to next timer2Elapsed, after finish countdown and go back to timer1Elapsed for countdown and so on repeat process for 5 times. seems like (A -> B -> A -> B ... 5 times) in condition A and B has fix time, just say A counting for 1 minute and B counting for 30 seconds. Please help and please don't typos because i am beginner. Correct me if my code is wrong. please be generous.

```
- (void) timer2Elapsed:(id)timer
{
    ...

    if (remainingTime <= 0)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.99 target:self selector:@selector(timer3Elapsed:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

    myDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d : %d : %d", hour , minute, second];
}

- (void) timer1Elapsed:(id)timer
{
    ...

    if (remainingTime <= 0)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.99 target:self selector:@selector(timer2Elapsed:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

    myDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d : %d : %d", hour , minute, second];
}
```

this is my button

```
- (IBAction)startBtn:(id)sender {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.99 target:self selector:@selector(timer1Elapsed:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need one timer to call the other, you can use the following code

```
+ (void) timer2Elapsed:(id)timer
{
    static int numberOfTimes = 0;
    if(numberOfTimes >= 5)
    {
        numberOfTimes = 0;
        return;
    }
    numberOfTimes ++;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(timer1Elapsed:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void) timer1Elapsed:(id)timer
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(timer2Elapsed:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)startTimers
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(timer1Elapsed:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Comment: how to use it for loop? just say for 5 times repeat?

Comment: add a counter variable in your class, that increases each time a timer is called, when it reaches 5, dont schecdule a new timer

Comment: @Piyo check updated answer, it shows how to limit it to 5 times using static int

Comment: your + (void) timer2Elapsed:(id)timer is wrong. and why go back to timer1Elapsed instead startTimers. i have 2 timer process to loop here. i think people in here havent yet make timer like i do so can't understand my problem.

Comment: what i dont understand is what are you trying to obtain? are you trying to refresh a view, or what?

Comment: i edited my post, i use new code like you suggest it, please watch for a moment and help me. what i want is loop process.